# How to append pandas dataframe from different size lists using python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want create pandas data frame as per below image from different size of lists:

[dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDCTV.jpg)

Below is my lists:

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
C=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]
```

Below is my python code:

```
import pandas as pd

A=[1,2,3]
B=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
C=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12]

lenA = len(A)
lenB = len(B)
lenC = len(C)

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A', 'B','C'])
count1=0
count2=0
for i,v1 in enumerate(A):
    count1+=count1+i
    for j,v2 in enumerate(B):
        for k, v3 in enumerate(C):
            count2 += count2 + j
            if(count1<1):
                if (count2 < 2):
                    df = df.append({'A': v1, 'B': v2,'C':v3}, ignore_index=True)
            else:
                df = df.append({'A': v1, 'B': v2,'C':v3}, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

But I couldn't get my expected output. Guide me to get the output as per in the image using A, B and C lists. Thanks in advance.

Comment: kindly post ur expected output, as data, not pics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain that `lenC` is divisible by both `lenA` and `lenB`, then you can use `np.repeat`:

```
pd.DataFrame({
    'A': np.repeat(A, lenC//lenA),
    'B': np.repeat(B, lenC//lenB),
    'C': C
})
```

Output:

```
    A  B   C
0   1  1   1
1   1  1   2
2   1  2   3
3   1  2   4
4   2  3   5
5   2  3   6
6   2  4   7
7   2  4   8
8   3  5   9
9   3  5  10
10  3  6  11
11  3  6  12
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This output only I expected. But can you  guide me with for loop? Because I want to change the length sometime. Not always same length as per you code. Thanks..